# Can't grok multiline logs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have logs where each event is:

```
ExitNode FF33F91CC06B6CC5C3EE804E7D8DBE42CB5707F9
Published 2017-11-05 02:55:09
LastStatus 2017-11-05 04:02:27
ExitAddress 66.42.224.235 2017-11-05 04:06:26
```

I tried to use multiline:

```
input {
   file {
     path => "/path/input"
   }
}
filter {
  multiline {
    pattern => "^\b[A-Za-z]{8}\b"
      what => "next"
  }
}
filter {
  multiline {
    pattern => "^\b[A-Za-z]{8}\b"
      what => "next"
  }
}
filter {
  multiline {
    pattern => "^\b[A-Za-z]{11}\b"
      what => "previous"
  }
}
output {
  file {
    codec => rubydebug
    path => "/path/output"
  }
}
```

And I get something like this:

```
{
          "path" => "/path/input",
    "@timestamp" => 2017-11-05T10:25:34.112Z,
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "HOST",
       "message" => "ExitNode FE3CB742E73674F1BC2382723209ECEE44AD4AEC\nPublished 2017-11-04 20:34:55\nLastStatus 2017-11-04 21:03:26\nExitAddress 77.250.227.12 2017-11-04 21:06:45",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "multiline"
    ]
}
```

And I can't grok this message field because I don't know how to remove or replace `\n` and `gsub => ["message", "\n", "Line_Break"]` doesn't work properly.
Thanks

Comment: I got this to work: `mutate {  gsub => ["message", "[\r\n]","_"] }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment of @baudsp:

```
mutate { 
  gsub => 
    ["message", "[\r\n]","_"] 
}
```